# Processing - rule of cosines (sss) - NaN

Tags: java, processing, trigonometry, nan

I am working on a simple inverse kinematic delta robot controller with Processing. I am stuck at the rule of cosines. I have the length of the three sides and wish to get the angles. But `float angle = acos((sq(humerus)+sq(ulna) - sq(radius))/(2 * humerus * ulna));`
always returns NaN. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably want to use the law of *cosines* if you know the sides:

[image]

In Java terms, to solve for the angle *`C`* (opposite to side of length `c`) we would have

```
Math.acos((a*a + b*b - c*c) / (2*a*b))
```

---

There are a couple reasons why you could be getting `NaN`:

- One of your side lengths is negative, so when you square root it you receive `NaN`.
- Your triangle can't really exist based on the side lengths you specified. Look at this documentation for [`acos`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#acos%28double%29):

  > If the argument is `NaN` or its absolute value is greater than `1`, then the result is `NaN`.

Comment: Ah my bad, I got mixed up in the title, I am using law of cosines. The issue is that it returns a NaN.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help. If i scale all my values in floats 0-1 it should work? All my dimentions are positive.

Comment: @bob_walter Not necessarily, it depends on the relative sizes of the side lengths. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality).

Comment: Regarding the side lengths... Just to make it a bit more explicit, you must have `|a| + |b| > |c|`, `|b| + |c| > |a|` and `|c| + |a| > |b|` to have a triangle (replace `>` with `>=` for a degenerate triangle with all sides collinear).

Comment: Ah once again, developer error. Thanks everyone for helping out!

Answer (score 1):

If you check the javadoc for [Math.acos](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#acos%28double%29), you see the following:

```
If the argument is NaN or its absolute value is greater than 1, then the result is NaN.
```

So, there are two possibilities:

1. The numerator is greater than the denominator in absolute value, resulting in a fraction that exceeds 1.0.  The arccosine will therefore return a NaN.
2. One of the square roots is returning a NaN.  As we see from the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt%28double%29): `If the argument is NaN or less than zero, then the result is NaN.`

So, I would check your values for humerus, radius and ulna.  It's possible that you either allowed a slightly too large numerator (e.g., via floating point error) or you had a vector rather than a scalar value for your arm bone measurements (resulting in a negative rather than a positive argument to square root).